# money-rails: don’t initialize monetized fields with 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Take the following model as an example:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
    monetize :price_cents, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }
    …
}
```

with this schema

```
create_table "products", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "price_cents", null: false
    …
end
```

When I create a new `Product` that has nil `price` instead of the value being nil I get a `Money` object with the value of 0. Undesirable for my use case because I’d rather have empty values set explicitly rather than implicitly.

Setting `default:nil` in `config.amount_column` only gives me the desired behaviour on initialization, but then `price` gets set to the `Money` object of 0 if `Product` is updated with `price` still set to nil.

How do I stop this behaviour?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `t.integer "price_cents", null: true`?

Comment: Right, made a typo when I was modifying my examples for brevity. It actually is just `price_cents`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the `null: false` option.

Comment: I still want to enforce non-null vales for `pirce_cents`, I just don’t want that enforced by the gem which is always making that value not null.

Comment: Okay, now that's confusing..where does `Money` object come from and which gem you use?

Comment: I see..you use `monetize` gem..well..if I m understanding your concern, you want `money` to be `nil`, in that case if you think practically, `money` can't be `nil` but some value atleast 0..if you still want it to be nil, you can have a callback like `before_save` where you can modify the `money` as per your requirement and set it to the corresponding `attribute`.